# Calculate total distance swift iOS

Tags: swift, function, methods, distance, tracking

So in my current `project` Im doing a method which calculates the saved emission when driving a moped compared to a average car. The function contains two parts, the `method` (the calculation) and the `tracker function`. The main problem is that the tracker function somehow **does not seem to track at all**.

My main question is, how do I get the tracker function to **always** track while the app is on?

This is the tracker function

```
var startLocation:CLLocation!
var lastLocation: CLLocation!
var traveledDistance:Double = 0

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    if startLocation == nil {
        startLocation = locations.first
    } else {
        if let lastLocation = locations.last {
            let distance = startLocation.distanceFromLocation(lastLocation)
            let lastDistance = lastLocation.distanceFromLocation(lastLocation)
            traveledDistance += lastDistance
            print( "\(startLocation)")
            print( "\(lastLocation)")
            print("FULL DISTANCE: \(traveledDistance)")
            print("STRAIGHT DISTANCE: \(distance)")
            var travelDistance = setData("distance")
        }
    }
    lastLocation = locations.last
}
```

And this is the method

```
func calculateEmission(numbers: Int...) -> Double{
    let recordedDistance = getData("distance")

    let dis = recordedDistance
    let emissionAve = 0.16

    let calculatedEmission : Double = Double(dis) * Double(emissionAve)

    print(calculatedEmission, "kg Co2")
    return calculatedEmission
}
```

Comment: What makes you believe this method should be called? Did you create a `CLLocationManager` somewhere, did you set it's `delegate` to an instance of whatever class contains this method?

Comment: This question is still very vague. Please be precise about what information you are looking for.

Comment: Did you get prompted to grant access for location services?

Comment: @Sethmr Sorry! Was a bit distracted when writing this question, but my question is "how do I get the tracker function to always track while the app is on"?

Comment: @MwcsMac I will se if that solves the problem. If it not, it might be because I don't really know where/when to call the tracker function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the following in your info.plist. Then you should get prompted to allow access to the location services.

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Needs access to access GPS</string>
<key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key>
<string>Needs access to access GPS</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Needs access to access GPS</string>
```

You should have some thing like this in viewDidLoad.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }
```

Comment: So I tried to do as you suggested, it seem to work so far, but when I get the "Need access to access GPS" message it disappear before I can even click on `allow button`. And I also receives following message in console **"Trying to start MapKit location updates without prompting for location authorization. Must call -[CLLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization] or -[CLLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization] first."** @MwcsMac

Comment: What device are you trying this on? The console message is to be expected because you did not all access, because of not being able to hit allow.

Comment: it works perfectly on all the simulated phones, but I only get this error when trying it on my phone (iPhone 6).